# converting rewrite rules from htaccess to nginx

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx

Anyone please help me to convert following rules in `.htaccess` to nginx

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*).html$ /cat.php?cat=$2&page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*).html$ /cat.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*).html$ /search.php?cat=$2&page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*).html$ /search.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^others/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ /other.php?cat=$3&page=$2&data=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^others/(.*)/(.*).html$ /other.php?cat=$2&data=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)-by-(.*)-download.html$ /video.php?title=$1&artist=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [htAccess to Nginx converter](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess)

```
# nginx configuration
location /category {
rewrite ^/category/(.)/(.).html$ /cat.php?cat=$2&page=$1 break;
rewrite ^/category/(.*).html$ /cat.php?cat=$1 break;
}
location /search {
rewrite ^/search/(.)/(.).html$ /search.php?cat=$2&page=$1 break;
rewrite ^/search/(.*).html$ /search.php?cat=$1 break;
}
location /others {
rewrite ^/others/(.)/(.)/(.*).html$ /other.php?cat=$3&page=$2&data=$1 break;
rewrite ^/others/(.)/(.).html$ /other.php?cat=$2&data=$1 break;
}
location /download {
rewrite ^/download/(.)-by-(.)-download.html$ /video.php?title=$1&artist=$2 break;
}
```

Anyway you can do this by your own because these are simple url format rewrite rules.
For example in .htAccess

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.)/(.).html$ /cat.php?cat=$2&page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Above rules says when there a request withfollowing url format

**^category/(.)/(.).html$**  ( http://myhostname.com/category/[page-id]/[category-id].html )

rewrite it to following format

**/cat.php?cat=$2&page=$1** ( http://myhostname.com/cat.php?cat=[category-id]&page=[page-id])

And this rule translated to nginx as follows

```
location /category {
rewrite ^/category/(.)/(.).html$ /cat.php?cat=$2&page=$1 break;
rewrite ^/category/(.*).html$ /cat.php?cat=$1 break;
}
```

Comment: @ Deshan: Thanks for your suggestion. But I have tried already. Its not working.